# Can i use quilljs with php?

Tags: javascript, php, populate

i am trying for some days to make this working but i really can't alone..
I want to use quilljs on my project, but because i dont know js, i want to insert data using php.
I found this [QuillJS doesn't work with textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40432577/quilljs-doesnt-work-with-textarea) i tryed everything but its just not working.

In the end i created an input hidden but i dont know how to populate it, i need js for that. Please help me.

This is my quill html code.

```
            <form action="test.php" method="post" class="col s12" id="idform">
                <div class="row">
                    
 
                                  
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
      <!-- Snow Editor start -->
  <section class="snow-editor" >
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-content">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col s12">
                <div id="snow-wrapper">
                  <div id="snow-container">
                    <div class="quill-toolbar">
                      <span class="ql-formats">
                        <select class="ql-header browser-default">
                          <option value="1">Heading</option>
                          <option value="2">Subheading</option>
                          <option selected>Normal</option>
                        </select>
                      </span>
                      <span class="ql-formats">
                        <button class="ql-bold"></button>
                        <button class="ql-italic"></button>
                        <button class="ql-underline"></button>
                      </span>
                      <span class="ql-formats">
                        <button class="ql-list" value="ordered"></button>
                        <button class="ql-list" value="bullet"></button>
                      </span>
                      <span class="ql-formats">
                        <button class="ql-link"></button>
                       <!-- <button class="ql-image"></button> -->
                        <button class="ql-video"></button>
                      </span>
                      <span class="ql-formats">
                        <button class="ql-formula"></button>
                        <button class="ql-code-block"></button>
                      </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input name="inputname" type="hidden">
                        <div id="editor-container" class="editor">
                                
                      <p><br></p>

                      <p><br></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!-- Snow Editor end -->

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="row">


                    <div class="col s6 m6 l6">

                    
                        <button id="idbutton" class="waves-effect waves-light btn right" type="submit" name="postbutton">Post</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I tryed this, but is not working. It insert on my db but without any info (the input area is not populated).

```
  var form = document.querySelector('form');
form.onsubmit = function() {
  // Populate hidden form on submit
  var about = document.querySelector('input[name=inputname]');
  about.value = JSON.stringify(quill.getContents());
  
  console.log("Submitted", $(form).serialize(), $(form).serializeArray());
  
  // No back end to actually submit to!
  alert('Open the console to see the submit data!')
  return false;
};
```